# New Tomcat server redirecting to old server site

Tags: tomcat

We are standing up a Dev server for an app site through Tomcat 9.0.12. We installed Tomcat, but copied some files over from Production. At some point https://appdev.domain is redirecting to https://application.domain/ords/, the production portal log-in. If we navigate to appdev.domain/ords/ it resolves to the correct portal log-in, but just browsing to the base site redirects to the prod log-in page. This may be resolved with a fresh installation of Tomcat, but I was wondering if there is a file somewhere in the Tomcat 9.0 directory that is causing this redirect.

We confirmed DNS and Load balancer point to the right IPs.

Comment: Search for `application.domain` in the files from Tomcat's `conf` folder. If you find something, add it to your question. Otherwise it's your application that generates the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

There was a redirect set up in tomcat9.0\webapps\root\index.jsp file on prod it was redirecting application.domain to application.domain/ords, but in the transition to dev, it was still going to application.domain/ords instead of appdev.domain/ords.